# Awaiting asynchronous subscribe in angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Google Firestore to update data asynchronously in Angular, so I am using subscribe() to stream the data with the following code:

```
this.localGame = new Game();
this.game.subscribe(data => {
      // @ts-ignore
      this.localGame = data.game;
      console.log('A');
    });
console.log('B');
if (this.localGame.team2.length >= this.localGame.team1.length) {
      this.localGame.team1.push(this.playerName);
```

I want the data to stream constantly (I'm also updating the DB), but I also need 'A' to be printed before 'B' at least once to avoid this.localGame.team2 being undefined. I am fairly new to all of this, could someone please explain if there is a clean way of doing this without forcing a timeout or something?

Comment: Move all of your logic inside the callback passed to `this.game.subscribe`.

Comment: Oh wait - is `this.game` an `Observable`? If so, then brace yourself for the very, very steep learning curve for Reactive Extensions: https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview

Comment: For async you can reach data inside  subscribe. You need to do your job inside it or use promise await rather than observable

Comment: @Dai Yes it is, and I can't move the logic inside because I need everything outside to only happen one time, and then I need this.localGame to load all the time.

Comment: @pc_coder I thought promise only happens one time, but I could be wrong. Could you please explain how I would add that in?

Comment: As you know we don't know what are you trying to do. But if you are rendering this component on any route directly. You can check router resolvers from https://medium.com/nonstopio/angular-resolve-property-in-the-router-b98c759491c7

Comment: @babajaj You can do that (make your code do init only once) but you need to be familiar with RxJS first.